# print out the number of two values in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a database in which there are people. They have genders. How would I count male and female separate.

```
SELECT count(id_osb)
from ds_osebe
where spol = 'M'
or spol = 'Z';
```

this is how i can get the number of male and female combined

I do not know how to make this, it's my second day learning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use grouping (group by)

```
SELECT spol, count(id_osb)
from ds_osebe
where spol = 'M'
or spol = 'Z'
group by spol
```

NOTE: replace spol if it doesn't denote sex

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select SUM(case spol when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male_cnt
SUM(case spol when 'Z' then 1 else 0 end) as female_cnt
from ds_osebe;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) over (partition by spol) as qty, spol
from ds_osebe
/*if you have more than 2 gender options*/
where spol in ('Z', 'M');
```